# R: Base functions cannot use object from the package Caper

Tags: r, package, linear-regression

I'm running a phylogenetic analysis using the `caper` package, where the regression function (which uses phylogeneticaly independent contrasts) is `crunch`. The `crunch` function uses an object internal to the `caper` package called `caic`.

The model is started via:

```
crunchMod <- crunch(y ~ f(x), data = comparison)
```

When I run `summary(crunchMod)` I am given a format identical to that of a summary produced from the `lm()` function.

However, in an attempt to begin checking model assumptions by entering `rstandard(crunchMod)`, I receive the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("rstandard") : 
no applicable method for 'rstandard' applied to an object of class "caic"
```

Reading through http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caper/vignettes/caper.pdf on pages 19-20, I find that `plot(crunchMod)` uses a wrapper to enable the checking of regression assumptions. However, these are graphical checks for:

```
residuals vs Fitted values
standardized residuals vs theoretical quantities [QQ plot]
sqrt(standardized residuals) vs fitted values [Scale-location]
standardized residuals vs leverage).
```

Does anyone know how to access the standardized residuals using my own wrapper, or allow me to access p-values instead of the graphical images?

Comment: It would be useful to put the output of `dput(comparison)` in your post so we might replicate your situation.

Comment: Look at the structure of crunchMod (`str(crunchMod`)) . To access the relevant bit you need to use rstandard(crunchMod$mod). Note `class(crunchMod$mod)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is pretty simple, but only after going round in circles for a while with that second `if()` statement in `crunch().` Looking at the summary method for `caic`, it's just a subset of the entire summary / model

```
> summary.caic
function (object, ...) 
{
    summary(object$mod, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:caper>
```

You can see the names of the entire model show there are useful statistics in the rest of it.

```
names(summary(crunchMod))
# [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients" 
# [5] "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared"    
# [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

Note that only the `mod` section inherits from `lm()` You can check out all the inheritence of the `crunchMod` objects with

```
> sapply(crunchMod, is)
$contrast.data
[1] "list"   "vector"

$mod
[1] "lm"       "oldClass"

$data
[1] "comparative.data"
```